# How do I call back to the main node so I can switch to a different scene in javafx

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

so I am trying to switch to a different scene in javafx. I am working on a project where the user will select on a food category via a combobox, which will switch to a new scene that has all the recipes under that specific category.

The problem is I am able to load my MainMenuScene, but I am not sure how to switch to a different scene, which I think is because of how I have structured my code.

My code is structured where I can GUIAPP (which starts the entire GUI)

```
    private static View myView;
    private static Recipe myRecipe; 



    public GUIApp() {

        myView = new View(); 
        myRecipe = new Recipe(); 

    }   

    public static View getView() {
        return myView; 
    }
    public static Recipe getRecipe() {
        return myRecipe;
    }

    @Override 
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Starting app...");
        myView.setStage(primaryStage); 

    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        myRecipe = new Recipe(); 
        launch(args); 
    }
}
```

Then View, which sets the primary Stage (which is MainMenuScene)

```
    private Stage myStage;
    private Scene myMainMenuScene;
    private Scene myMealScene;

    public View() {

        myMainMenuScene = new MainMenuScene(new BorderPane()); 

    }

    public Stage getStage() {
        return myStage;
    }

    public Scene getMealScene() {
        return myMealScene; 
    }


    public void setStage(Stage primaryStage) {
        myStage = primaryStage;
        myStage.setScene(myMainMenuScene);
        myStage.setTitle("Recipe Database");
        myStage.setWidth(600);
        myStage.setHeight(400);

        Scene scene = myMainMenuScene;
        myStage.setScene(scene);
        myStage.show();

    }



}
```

Here is MainMenuScene, where it calls the recipe code I had previously made

```
    private BorderPane myRoot;
    private String f, t;
    Label label = new Label();

    public MainMenuScene(Parent root) {
        super(root);

        myRoot = (BorderPane) root; 
        BorderPane titleBox = new BorderPane();
        titleBox.setStyle("-fx-font: 24 arial;");
        myRoot.setTop(titleBox);

        Text title = new Text("Recipe Database Tool");
        title.setFont(new Font(50));
        titleBox.setCenter(title);

        //VBox and HBox creation 
        VBox leftBox = new VBox();
        VBox rightBox = new VBox();
        VBox centerBox = new VBox();        

        //Button search = new Button("Recipe Categories");
        Button create = new Button("Create/Upload a New Recipe");

        //Creates a combobox that gets the category name from Recipe
        ComboBox<String> search = new ComboBox<String>();
        search.getItems().addAll(GUIApp.getRecipe().getCategory()); 

        search.setOnAction((e) -> {
            search.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
        });
        /*
        ****//Create a button that switches to MealScene when a category is selected 
        Button select = new Button("Select");
        select.setOnAction((e) -> {
            View.getStage().setScene(View.getMealScene());****

        });
        */
        //myRoot for each Box 
        myRoot.setLeft(leftBox);
        myRoot.setRight(rightBox);
        myRoot.setCenter(centerBox);

        //adding the search categories button to the left box
        leftBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        leftBox.setSpacing(30);
        leftBox.getChildren().add(search);

        //adding the create a new recipe to the right box
        rightBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        rightBox.setSpacing(30);
        rightBox.getChildren().add(create); 


    }



}
```

I tried calling the button by using View, but I am getting an error that I am not sure how to fix.

Here's the error: It's asking for `View.getStage()` to make getStage a static method in View, which I don't want to do and `View.getMealScene` to also become static

Please let me know! I would love to learn how to prevent this in the future

Comment: "I am getting an error that I am not sure how to fix." Do you think it would be helpful to post that error message instead of hoping that people will copy all your code, compile it and then tell you what the problem is? Whenever you are asking for free assistance, you should do your best to minimize the amount of effort on the part of the people you're asking.

Comment: I fixed it by adding the error

Comment: If you just want to switch the view in the same window, then you should look at the CardLayout. This handles different views in the same space, only one of which is visible at any time.